# Angular 2 is not working on ie 9

Tags: angular, polyfills, es6-shim

I've been trying to run an Angular 2 application as a template but while it works really well in Chrome and after adding polyfills it worked on IE 10 and 11 I'm struggling to get it working in IE9!

I added Shims polyfills for IE.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.3/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classlist/2014.01.31/classList.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blob-polyfill/1.0.20150320/Blob.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/typedarray.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/formdata.js"></script>

  <![endif]-->
```

I am getting this error http://prntscr.com/eeytvq

Comment: can you try using core-js instead of es6-shim? core-js provides better es6 compliance. core-js is actually recommended over es6-shim by the Angular2 team.

Comment: It is not working again on ie 9 only

Comment: i think you'll have to post more of your code. i'm guessing... do you use absolute URLs for your templates or HTTP calls?

Comment: I am using relative URLs for the templates. Application is quite big to share here

Comment: what version of angular2?

Comment: "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137020/discussion-between-bhawna-and-pixelbits).