# Angular2 app is not working in IE 9

Tags: angular

I am working on app which needs to be run in IE 9 as well, but when I enabled polyfills app is not working.

```
Imported polyfills:

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

import 'classlist.js';

import 'mdn-polyfills/Object.assign';

import 'web-animations-js';

import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

with these polyfills my app is working on IE 10 and 11. In IE 9 its showing following exception:
[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42548126/angular-2-is-not-working-on-ie-9

Comment: form console error I under stood that reflect-metadata shim is required. I have searched in net and added reflect-metadata npm package and imported in polyfills still its showing same error. 
I am not sure statement i used to import in polyfills is correct
import 'reflect-metadata/Reflect' is this correct way to import package